# add date upon checkbox tick vba

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

In excel vba I have added a checkbox to a worksheet, once this checkbox is ticked, I want to move a range of data from one worksheet to another. I have already written the code that moves the data across the worksheets, but I just want to find out how to add the date (and time maybe) that the checkbox was clicked into the range of cells that is being moved across,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the time call `Now` and store that value wherever you want your date-time stamp to be